# addLoadEvent is not helping with onload conflict

Tags: javascript, onload

I'm using the popular addLoadEvent as follows for all my JS loading:

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent( locationToggle );
addLoadEvent( step1 );
addLoadEvent( step2 );
addLoadEvent( step3 );
addLoadEvent( getCounties );
addLoadEvent( mapSelection);
```

Everything I've read suggests this is a fairly bullet proof way of avoiding onload conflicts. And yet this method doesn't appear to working any better than wrapping the functions in an anonymous window.onload function. Both methods are causing identical onload conflicts with this set of functions.

I am loading these functions from within the same file as the addLoadEvent function itself. I'm also using calender.js which is a third party file which uses mootools 1.2.4 in an additional file. My files are otherwise free of Javascript.

First, could someone verify I've not damaged the code and I'm using it right. Second could someone suggest why the above is not resolving the conflicts?

**edit**
The problem persists with all other Javascript files disabled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is fine. The problem is that setting [event handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_events.html) in the **DOM 0 way doesn't ensure** that they won't **replaced by other code**.

You may try the **new W3C standard** [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) and the IE version [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343(VS.85).aspx), because the handlers you attach by them cannot be replaced by 3rd party code.

```
// window.onload W3C cross-browser with a fallback
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", func, false);
  else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", func);
  else { // fallback
    var old = window.onload;
    window.onload = function() {
      if (old) old();
      func();
    };
  }
}
```

Note, that IE will execute the function in reversed order not in the order you added them (if this is a concern).

Finally, I don't know when you want to run your code, but if you don't want to wait for images to load **you can execute your functions earlier** then window.onload.

[Dean Edwards](http://dean.edwards.name) has a **[nice script](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/06/again/)** which will let you to do that.

With this you can attach your functions for an **earlier** event: **document.ready** (DOMContentLoaded)

```
// document.ready
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  if (typeof func == "function") {
    addLoadEvent.queue.push(func);
  }
}
addLoadEvent.queue = [];

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Dean Edwards/Matthias Miller/John Resig

function init() {
  // quit if this function has already been called
  if (arguments.callee.done) return;

  // flag this function so we don't do the same thing twice
  arguments.callee.done = true;

  // kill the timer
  if (_timer) clearInterval(_timer);

  // do stuff: execute the queue
  var que = addLoadEvent.queue;
  var len = que.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (typeof que[i] == "function") {
      que[i]();
    }
  }
};

/* for Mozilla/Opera9 */
if (document.addEventListener) {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
}

/* for Internet Explorer */
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_win32)
  document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)>"
                +"<\/script>");
  var script = document.getElementById("__ie_onload");
  script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == "complete") {
      init(); // call the onload handler
    }
  };
/*@end @*/

/* for Safari */
if (/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // sniff
  var _timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
      init(); // call the onload handler
    }
  }, 10);
}

/* for other browsers */
window.onload = init;
```

Note: the usage is the same for both methods as it was for your version.

​

Comment: OK Now it works. Apparently I need a more upto date reference for Javascript :) Sorrry for the long time in replying - I began to suspect one the functions was broken. Turned out that was right which didn't help at all.

Comment: You may want to check out Crockford's videos on the language. He's one of the best: http://javascript.crockford.com/ (YUI Theater)