# Queries not retaining in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

Can't figure out why queries made in the search box are not being retained in IE (of course). Can somebody please open the link below in IE

http://www.adhuntr.com/p/results.html?ie=UTF-8&q=ipad+mini&min=&max=&l=all&c=all&t=&p=

Comment: type in a query and you'll see

Comment: Check my answer, because it seems your `XML requests` were only based on `XMLHttpRequest()`

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to your `addLoadEvent()` function, calling just `fillSearchBox()` from the IE Dev Console fires this function correctly and populate the input box with the query.

Specially, the error is in this call: `addLoadEvent(fillSearchBox);`

I tried using the [updated suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196572/addloadevent-is-not-helping-with-onload-conflict) for the addLoadEvent function in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N25BY/) without any success.

Since you are using jQuery just a little further down the code you can use this instead. Sample in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N25BY/1/):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   fillSearchBox()
});
```

BTW, you have a typo on `input.result`, which is why the search does not submit automatically when you select a suggestion:

```
input
    .attr ("autocomplete", "off")
    .autocomplete ("http://clients1.google.com/complete/search", options)
    .result (function () { searchform.submit(); }); //<== typo in this line, should be submit
```

You really should move all your inline code to external files, you have an awful lot of inline JavaScript and CSS in the page which need to be downloaded every time the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing by retaining, you mean show up in the search bar as you are typing, or suggestion? Well, it could be because, that older versions of IE namely 6,7  do not support the Ajax `XMLHttpRequest()` object, therefore... you have to change your ajax code, namely less than just one line, to check also for `window.ActiveXObject` of IE. by doing

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
        else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
        else {
            alert('Please update your browse, to see Ajax in Action :) ');
    }
```

Comment: Weird. He appears to reference the jQuery library, why not just use that for the Ajax requests? :(

Comment: `1` I am jQuery noob, and `2` I like people (myself) to actually lean about Js, and Ajax before they can jump to frame works

Comment: Ok, that's fair enough and don't disagree, too many people don't do that so I commend you for that. For a production system though, I'd go the jQuery way since you are already using it.

Comment: Yes, but one thing also, I don't get is that, jQuery is supposed to be good with helping ajax work, and be compatible with browser issues, so.. as you say.. if he is using jQuery, then how come he IE is not working for him

Comment: According to your bit of code it is not using jQuery, if it was then the cross-browser issue would have been handled. I mistakingly thought the commenter was the OP. I'll dig into the code.

Comment: I added answer with where the fault lies, it's not using jQuery hence the cross-browser issue in this instance. I'm not sure exactly *why* there is an error though. Using jQuery will fix it though...